# python keras Convolution2D layer works not correctly and gets a wrong result

Tags: python, keras-layer

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=(3, 256, 256)))
```

[This example](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) says :

> now `model.output_shape == (None, 64, 256, 256)`

however in my console, I got the reult `model.output_shape == (None, 3, 256, 64)`
I believe there must be someone else got the same wrong result, does anyone have solved this problem？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same [link you give](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#convolution2d) says :

> dim_ordering: 'th' or 'tf'. In 'th' mode, the channels dimension (the depth) is at index 1, in 'tf' mode is it at index 3. It defaults to the image_dim_ordering value found in your Keras config file at ~/.keras/keras.json. If you never set it, then it will be "tf".

So your input_shape is like theano's and your output looks like your backend is tensorflow. If you want to use it like this, change your convolution2D layer to :

```
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=(3, 256, 256), dim_ordering='th'))
```

or change your images so that the input shape is `(256,256,3)`.

Your question formulation is not really clear, you don't give much information and the display is quite aggressive btw.

Comment: thanks a lot. this is my first time to seek help from others on this site.so sorry to be inpolite :)

Comment: It's alright, just try to read all the info there is on the website about how to format your questions. Get inspiration from highly voted questions ;) and if you found the answer useful you can close it by accepting the answer.

Comment: I've edited your question. But for your information, in your title, programs rarely give the wrong answer, it gives what it has been written to give. If the result is not what you expected, probably you are not using it correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I will make it better next time. I'm trying to use this tool for some simple apps. The code is very readable and I can also learn many programming skills.Thanks again~~